# Is there a maximum limit for the length (number of characters) of identifier names in C++?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

What is the maximum limit for the number of characters in a variable name in C++, if any?
I am using a g++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Identifiers-implementation.html

> For internal names, all characters are significant. For external names, the number of significant characters are defined by the linker; for almost all targets, all characters are significant.

So it is implementation/target specific and you will have to check the documentation for your one.